# How is global scoping done in F#

Tags: f#, scope, global-variables

I need to create a collection in F# that has a key value pair and is global in scope.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Globals =
  let map = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
```

Then use it unqualified throughout your program:

```
map.Add(1, "a")
map.Add(2, "b")
map |> Seq.iter (fun (KeyValue(k, v)) -> printfn "Key: %d, Value: %s" k v)
```

Comment: Is `<_, _>` superfluous here?

Answer (score 4):

depending on what kind of project you are doing the best method might be do just declare it in a module:

```
module GlobalVals =

    let myCollection = .... // whatever
```

you can just use it with

```
GlobalVals.myCollection...
```